# Me salta un error IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python y estaba intentado crear un programa que con dos numeros que ingreso me diga si los valores son iguales o no pero me salta ese error al ejecutar el programa.

```
def validar_numeros(n1):
if type(n1) == True:
else:
print("No iguales")
return "Iguales"

a = int(input("Ingresa un numero entero:"))
b = int(input("Introduce otro numero entero:"))
print(validar_numeros(a,b))
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa el indentado de tu código. ¿Es claro el porqué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te lanza tu **función** se debe a la indentación o sangrado. **En Python** y en otros lenguajes como Haskell son **estrictamente necesarios para que el lenguaje, en este caso Python pueda ser interpretado.**

De igual modo, tu función presenta varias intrucciones confusas como el uso de las estructuras de control `if-else` y el uso del `print` y `return`. Cuando estés trabajando con funciones, emplea como instrucción de imprimir en pantalla la intrucción `return`

Otro error con el que cuenta tu función, y que solucionando los errores previamente mencionados tampoco retornaría una salida correcta se debe a que estás preguntando si el tipo (`type`) de ambos datos son iguales. En ese caso, para un `input` como: `15 y 42` te va a retornar que son iguales, cuando no lo son. Eso se debe a que la función está evaluando si ambos tipos de datos primitivos son iguales, y en este caso, el tipo si lo son, pero los valores no

Así mismo, si quieres que la función pueda comparar ambos números ingresados y devuelva si sus valores son iguales o no, debes pasarle como parámetros a la función, esos dos valores, en este caso, `num1` y `num2`porque de lo contrario, te lanzará un nuevo error de tipo `TypeError` como el siguiente:

```
TypeError: validar_numeros() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Por último, personalmente, te aconsejo que las variables, clases, métodos... que implementes sean **autodescriptibles** (posean un nombre que **al leerlo se sepa que referencian**). Nunca se sabe si vas a trabajar con un equipo de programadores y analizando tu código se encontraran variables como `a, b, n1 y n2`

**Código completo**

```
def validar_numeros(num1, num2):
  if num1 == num2:
    return "Los valores ingresados son iguales"
  else:
    return "Los valores ingresados no son iguales"

numero1 = int(input("Introduzca un numero entero: "))
numero2 = int(input("Introduzca un segundo número: "))

print(validar_numeros(numero1, numero2))
```

Comment: Gracias me ha servido

Answer (score 0):

El codigo esta tal cual lo posteas ?

Ademas de la indentacion, despues del if no puedes dejar vacio! Prueba poniendo **Pass** y despues el else

Prueba asi

```
def validar_numeros(n1):
    if type(n1) == True:
        pass
    else:
        print("No iguales")
    return "Iguales"

a = int(input("Ingresa un numero entero:"))
b = int(input("Introduce otro numero entero:"))
print(validar_numeros(a,b))
```